# Problem with Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation

I'm now installing Ubuntu from a USB. I just clicked "Install Ubuntu" and the screen went black. I can't turn it off. It's a new Asus laptop with windows 10. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should try removing the USB disk and then press and hold the power key for like 10 seconds on your laptop to turn it off. You can do this even with the USB drive plugged in. Then make sure you made the bootable drive using some good utility like Rufus and chose GPT for UEFI Systems. (Ofcourse if your hard disk is GPT)

Comment: This is not really an answer, if it contains "probably try". If you want the OP to attempt something to clarify what happens in that case you should use comments.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)